# How to pass a Type parameter to a function in Dart?

Tags: dart

I want to pass a Type parameter to my function. Is that possible?

For example:

```
List getSomething(Type typeToReturn) {
    return List<dynamic, typeToReturn>();
}
```

My code:

```
List<charts.Series> getSeriesData(Type typeToReturn) {
    List<DateTime> dates = getDaysInBetween(startTime, DateTime.now());
    List<Map> data = [];
    dates.forEach((DateTime date) => data.add({
          'date': '${date.day.toString()}.${date.month.toString()}',
          'score': _getTotalScoreInSpecificDate(date)
        }));

    return [
      new charts.Series<dynamic, typeToReturn>(
        id: 'Score',
        colorFn: (_, __) => charts.MaterialPalette.blue.shadeDefault,
        domainFn: (data, _) => data['date'],
        measureFn: (data, _) => data['score'],
        data: data,
      )
    ];
  }
```

Comment: What is `List<dynamic, typeToReturn>` supposed to be?  `List` takes only one generic type parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to do something like this using generics, completely dropping your `typeToReturn` parameter:

```dart
List<charts.Series> getSeriesData<T>() {
    // ...

    return [
      new charts.Series<dynamic, T>(
        // ...
      )
    ];
  }
```

Also, I don't believe you can use a `Type` object dynamically as a type parameter. I *think* you can using `dart:mirrors`, but that library isn't compatible with Flutter and isn't really maintained anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use [Generics](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#why-use-generics), so the function will be something like this:

```
List<dynamic, T> getSomething<T>(T typeToReturn) {
    return List<dynamic, T>();
}
```

Comment: It returns `Error: 'typeToReturn' isn't a type` :\

Comment: can you add the code where the error occurs ?

Comment: Hey, @Michael Soliman thanks for replying. I think Ben's answers solved my issue.